# How can I access my vmware guest vm when host is using a vpn

Tags: vmware-workstation

I have VMware 10 on a windows 7 host.  If I create a vm (Ubuntu or debian) using either bridged or nat networking, when I start VPN on my host to connect to my corporate network, I can't use either ssh or winscp to access my guest vms.

What is the best networking configuration for this kind of situation? 
Note there are a variety of reason I want ot use ssh  to access the vm's console rather than using the VMware guest window mostly having ot do with simplicity of interface and accessibility.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your issue is with your VPN connection, not necessarily with your VMware setup.  Check your VPN to see if it allowing split tunneling.  That means that **only** the traffic destined for your corporate network will be routed through the VPN tunnel, and anything else will be routed normally.  I'm guessing that right now, you're routing **all** traffic through your VPN tunnel, which makes other hosts on your local LAN unreachable when the VPN tunnel is up.